# R - Do series of tasks by group in data.frame

Tags: r, data.table, bioconductor

I have 2 (very similar but not identical) data.frames that I am doing several tasks (more about that at the end) with a subset of.  The data.frame has 33 subsets that I want to do the tasks on.  I know I could do this with a for loop:

df (1 & 2)

```
subset     value1     value2
1            1          1
1            2          5
2            3          2
2            2          4
........
33           234        21 
33           2          5

subsets <- c(1:33)
for (i in subsets){
     subset <- df[df$subset == i,]
     ...do tasks...
}
```

However, I assume there must be a better way??  Perhaps with data.table, though this isn't a requirement. Some guidance on where to start would be helpful.

**Tasks**

The tasks I'm doing include:

- Create GRanges objects
- find Overlaps between df1 & 2
- Use overlaps to combine segments

## Example:

The below is for context.  Everything below works fine if I use the forloop structure above, but I'm just trying to wrap my head around how to do this for each File, instead of for the entire df, without doing a for loop for each File.

df1

```
File   Chromosome      Min      Max    CN.State
C_28        1            1       100        1
C_28        1            150     200        1
A_1         1            20       25        3
A_1         1            150     200        3

df1 <- data.frame(File=c("C_28","C_28","A_1","A_1"), 
+                      Chromosome=rep(1, 4),
+                      Min=c(1, 150, 20, 150),
+                      Max=c(100, 200, 25, 200),
+                      CN.State=c(1,1,3,3))
```

df2

```
File Chromosome Min Max CN.State
C_28          1   1 210        1
A_1           1  15 250        3

df2 <- data.frame(File=c("C_28","A_1"), 
+                      Chromosome=rep(1, 2),
+                      Min=c(1, 15),
+                      Max=c(210, 250),
+                      CN.State=c(1,3))
```

### Simplified Tasks

**Make Genomic Ranges Objects**

```
df1 <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(df1, keep.extra.columns = TRUE, seqnames.field="Chromosome", start.field="Min", end.field = "Max")
df2 <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(df2, keep.extra.columns = TRUE, seqnames.field = "Chromosome", start.field = "Min", end.field = "Max")
```

**Find overlaps & combine**

```
hits <- findOverlaps(df1, df2)
ranges(df1)[queryHits(hits)] <- ranges(df2)[subjectHits(hits)]
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, but I think you should look into splitting the original data.frame with `mydfList <- split(df, df$subset)` and then running your analysis in `lapply`.

Comment: This is technically no different than doing a for loop, though.  Except that I do all the splits first then lessen the amount of code by using lapply.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.  I was wondering if there was a way to do this more easily, such as using the data.table "by" functionality that I've used for more simple computations.  I hope that clarifies.